# Room UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, android-room

**Hello Everyone, I have an error like this**

Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: city.city_id (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY[1555])

**My City entity is:**

```
@Entity(tableName = "city")
data class City(
        val name: String,
        val country: String,
){
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
        @ColumnInfo(name = "city_id") var cityId: Int = 0
}
```

**My dao fun is:**

```
@Insert
    fun insertCities(vararg city: City)
```

**I want to insert like this:**

```
val berlin: City = City("Berlin", "Germany")
berlin.cityId = 2950159
val munich: City = City( "Munich", "Germany")
munich.cityId = 2867714
```

That cityId comes from an API but before I make request I want to initialize cities hardcode.
But I try this way and does not work.
If someone can help me I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)